# Rename Embedded data in ElementCollection

Tags: hibernate, jpa

**Note** this was promptly [fixed](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8630) by [Steve Ebersole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1082300/steve-ebersole), it's included in Hibernate 5.2.3. If you're stuck on earlier versions I'll add a workaround as answer.

I have the following working setup:

An `Embeddable` (boilerplate removed for readability)

```
@Embeddable
public class TypeValue {
    String type;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    String value;
}
```

And an `Entity` (boilerplate removed for readability)

```
@Entity
public class AggregatedTypeValue {
    @Id
    UUID id;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "type", column = @Column(name = "content_type")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = @Column(name = "content_value"))
    })
    TypeValue content;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "attribute_name")
    Map<String, TypeValue> attributes;
}
```

As you can see I used `MapKeyColumn` to rename the column where the key of the map is stored in. This works fine. However I also want to rename the columns used for the `Embaddable`.

From what I found this should be possible using `AttributeOverride`:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "value.type", column = @Column(name = "attribute_type")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "value.value", column = @Column(name = "attribute_value"))
})
@MapKeyColumn(name = "attribute_name")
Map<String, TypeValue> attributes;
```

However, this results in

1. type and value in the collection table are renamed correctly
2. the column storing the key is named "value" (`MapKeyColumn` is ignored)
3. an additional "hash" column is stored, which becomes part of the primary key and is apparently the result of a call to `hashCode` on the key.

Is there a way to rename the columns accordingly?

**edit**
I am using Hibernate 5.2.2.Final

Comment: FWIW Your code is fine, and follows what the spec says. MapKeyColumn should be supported, and there should be no additional persistable column(s) added by the implementation. Report as a bug perhaps

Comment: It is already a reported bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8630

Comment: Awesome, thanks for fixing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** this was promptly [fixed](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8630) by [Steve Ebersole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1082300/steve-ebersole), it's included in Hibernate 5.2.3. If you're stuck on earlier versions, here's what I did as a workaround.

I've added a new `Embeddable`

```
@Embeddable
public class AttributeName {
    String name;
}
```

And use it as key:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "key.name", column = @Column(name = "attribute_name", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "value.type", column = @Column(name = "attribute_type", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "value.value", column = @Column(name = "attribute_value", nullable = false))
})
Map<AttributeName, TypeValue> attributes;
```

This works as expected, however it also means that you'll have to access the actual key differently (e.g. `key.getName()`) and thus might not be what you want.