# @MapKeyClass missing column [hash] in table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a given Database (see SQL below) and try to map a map with a class (complexkey) as key, but run into a stracktrace and dont know how to fix it.

I try to create a Product with a map of attributes like this (see full code in [repo](https://github.com/svenhornberg/jpamapping)).

What I am trying to do:

```
ComplexKey complexKey = ComplexKey.builder().locale("de").name("att1").build();
Map<ComplexKey, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
attributes.put(complexKey, "val1");

Product pro = Product.builder().attributes(attributes).build();

productRepository.saveAndFlush(pro);
```

But I dont know how to fix the Schema-validation: missing column [hash] in table [complexkey]. 
Any Idea?

**STACKTRACE**

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [hash] in table [complexkey]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

I created a [repository](https://github.com/svenhornberg/jpamapping) for this problem. You just need to clone, docker-compose up and start spring boot.

**COMPLEXKEY**

```
@Embeddable
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ComplexKey {

    private String locale;

    private String name;

}
```

**PRODUCT**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "val")
    @MapKeyClass(ComplexKey.class)
    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name="COMPLEXKEY", joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"))
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="name", column = @Column(name= "name")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="locale", column = @Column(name= "locale")),
    })
    private Map<ComplexKey, String> attributes; 
}
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
    id SERIAL primary key,
    name varchar(255) not null
);



CREATE TABLE COMPLEXKEY (
    locale varchar(255) not null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    val varchar(255) not null, 
    product_id int not null REFERENCES product (id)
);
```

Comment: attribute override "name" should be of the form "key.{col}" to override the key columns.

Comment: still the same stackstrace / error

Comment: Likely you have the same problem as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232315/rename-embedded-data-in-elementcollection). A bug in Hibernate.

Comment: i will try it with the 5.2.3 as soon it will be released. thanks for the info